# Error "Oracle home contain invalid characters"

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

When I install Oracle 19C on my vmware windows 10 it. Show like in photo. How to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @dara any luck solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the download zip folder and retry the installation. This will solve the problem, indeed the software location will be generated without special characters.

Answer (score -1):

Choose an Oracle home that does not have invalid characters ('#','$').

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).